# Loading property from file into static variables using spring?

Tags: java, spring, properties, junit4

Problem: I want to load a value (from a property file) into a JUnit test's static variable to use it in a class rule.

I cannot use the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurator in the spring context because it will not wire in the static variables. 
While using

```
@Value("${port}")
private static int port;
```

Spring complains

`2012-12-06 11:39:39 o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor [WARN] Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static int OrderJobIT.port`

I can load the property file and extract the value from it using the java.util.Properties but that's not a clean solution. Is there a better way to do this using spring? Essentially I want to use the property value in a JUnit class rule.